# Why would I enroll in a Limited Purpose FSA, on top of an HSA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, insurance, hsa, fsa

Open enrollment is coming up and I have the option to open both an HSA and a [limited purpose FSA](http://www.asiflex.com/programs/limitedpurpose.htm), which **only** covers dental and vision expenses. Why would I participate in both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though your HSA may already cover vision and dental expenses, there are two reasons you still might want to consider a Limited Purpose FSA on top of an HSA:

1. If you anticipate enough [**other** expenses](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p502/ar02.html) to completely use up funds in your HSA (and remember, annual contributions to an HSA are [limited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_savings_account#Contribution_limits)), then you can use the FSA funds for the vision & dental expenses specifically, or
2. If you want your HSA balance to **accumulate** for future major health expenses.  HSA balances can carry over from one year to the next.

Be careful: Unlike an HSA's ability to carry over, FSAs are instead *use-it-or-lose-it* ... excess funds are forfeit at the end of the year. So, don't overfund beyond anticipated expenses, or you'll generously end up [subsidizing other members](http://www.probenefits.com/pub/faq/Question.html?id=129) in your company's medical plan.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

I maintain an HSA and a childcare FSA. Previously I maintained an FSA for planned medical procedures (for example I knew my spouse wanted LASIK surgery)

In my scenario I am maximizing contributions to all tax-advantaged vehicles.

So I fund my HSA to the maximum *and* my FSA to the maximum because I intend to keep my HSA as an investment account. I also anticipate spending every dime (and more) of my $5000 child-care FSA. Since I hand out roughly 30% of my income in taxes, being able to offload 5K to the FSA saves me ~$1500 annually.

Think of your FSA as an additional tax-advantaged vehicle for expenses you expect to incur during the calendar year. My HSA is, as far as I'm concerned, another name for a *slightly funny* retirement account.